# Right hand rule to measure direction of electric field

Tags: electromagnetism

The diagram: a positive plate is on the left of the page and a negative plate is on the right. The velocity of the particle is going down the page. So, with a right hand rule, I would point my thumb in the direction of the velocity (down) and my palm in the direction of the force. But what's the direction of the force? I thought that for a positive charge it would be going from the positive to the negative charge (left to right on the page), but it appears by an answer key that it's actually going from the left to the right, even for a positive charge... This would mean the magnetic force is pointing out of the page.

Help!

Comment: You are confusing the electric and magnetic forces. There is no magnetic field or force here. The electric force acts in the direction you say. I'm sorry I don't get the problem.

Comment: There is a velocity, electric force, and charged particle. F=qVB, so there is a magnetic field B.

Comment: No, there is no magnetic field, only an electric field. The full formula for the Lorentz force is $\vec{F} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v}\times\vec{B})$. Here you have $\vec{E}\neq 0$ and $\vec{B}=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since there is positive and negative plate on your question, the field you want to say to us  might be an electric field.
suppose that the positive plate on the left and the negative plate on the right creates an uniform electric field and the velocity of the particle is downward, it will make a projectile depending on the charged of particle. if the particle is proton, the trajectory  will go to the right since it will be attracted by negative plate. if the particle is electron, the trajectory go to the left since it will be attracted by positive plate.

Answer (score 1):

This is case of charged plates, so there would be Electric Field between the plates and **not** Magnetic Field. And we know that Electric force applies in direction of 
Electric Field( for +ve charge and opposite for -ve).

Direction of electric field is from high potential to low potential.

Answer (score 1):

You say the plates are charged.  This only implies an electric field; you haven't said anything suggesting a magnetic field.  For electric fields, you don't use the right-hand rule.  Instead, the force is just parallel (or anti-parallel) to the field.

The electric field points from positive to negative, so from left to right in your case.  The Lorentz force law says that for a purely electric field, the force is $\vec{F} = q\, \vec{E}$, where $q$ is the charge.  This means that a *positive* charge would experience a force from left to right.  But the electron is *negative*, so the force is right to left.

If you answer key says something else, either it is wrong or you haven't described the problem correctly for us.